# ¿Es posible detener la ejecucion de una funcion de script por un tiempo para ejecutar otra?

Tags: python, python-3.x

lo que pasa es lo siguiente, estoy haciendo un script de python que haga capturas de pantalla cada cierto tiempo para ver errores cuando yo no esté en mi pc, bueno, lo que pasa es que puse una función para eliminar dichas capturas despues de un tiempo, pero a la hora de eliminarlas no me deja porqué me aparece un error que dice algo como "El archivo está siendo usado por otro proceso", no deja eliminarlo y por ender el script deja de ejecutarse, lo que quiero es, detener la funcion de Tomar capturas de pantalla por un intervalo de 10 segundos y que en ese intervalo de 10 segundos se ejecute la funcion de Eliminar las imagenes, osea, para que no haya problema en el script y se pueda ejecutar sin problema alguno, espero recibir ayuda pronto, gracias y buen día.

Comment: Haz probado con un sleep

Comment: Si, ya lo he hecho, pero quiero que despues de pausar la funcion de tomar capturas de pantalla, se ejecute la funcion de borrar las imagenes y luego se vuelva a ejecutar la funcion de tomar capturas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible controlar el tiempo en que un proceso se ejecuta jugando con un condicional, un contador de tiempo y el operador matemático módulo de la forma siguiente.

```
import time

#contador de tiempo
time1=time.time()
count=0
while count<10:
     if time.time()-time1>10:
         count+=1
         time1=time.time()
     if count%2==0:
         function1()
     else:
         function2()
```

Con este código la función 1 se ejecutará durante los primeros 10 segundos luego se detendrá y comenzará a ejecutarse la función 2
durante otros 10 segundos y así sucesivamente.